# Categorical variable is split into 2 columns, how to mutate data frame so categorical variable is 1 column?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data

```
data <- data.frame(Month = c("Sep", "Oct", "Nov"),
                   Year = c(2021,2021,2021),
                   Active = c(20,15,29),
                   Inactive = c(40,32,20))
```

[image]

The columns "active" and "inactive" are counts but since I'm trying to make some graphs it's difficult to work with. My desired output would be to combine the columns into a new one that shows the following. "Status" would be the new column created.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(Active, Inactive), names_to = "Status", values_to = "Count")  %>% arrange(Status)
```